# Facebook Auth Login Issue

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with Facebook Auth in codeigniter 3.
Whenever I press for facebook login, it redirects to facebook ask for the permission and den returns code in link and its not redirecting it to my profile page.
Below is my controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User_Authentication extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        // Load facebook library
        $this->load->library('facebook');

        //Load user model
        //$this->load->model('user');
    }

    public function index(){
        $userData = array();

        // Check if user is logged in
        if($this->facebook->is_authenticated()){
            // Get user facebook profile details
            $userProfile = $this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');

            // Preparing data for database insertion
            $userData['oauth_provider'] = 'facebook';
            $userData['oauth_uid'] = $userProfile['id'];
            $userData['first_name'] = $userProfile['first_name'];
            $userData['last_name'] = $userProfile['last_name'];
            $userData['email'] = $userProfile['email'];
            $userData['gender'] = $userProfile['gender'];
            $userData['locale'] = $userProfile['locale'];
            $userData['profile_url'] = 'https://www.facebook.com/'.$userProfile['id'];
            $userData['picture_url'] = $userProfile['picture']['data']['url'];

            // Insert or update user data
            $userID = $this->user->checkUser($userData);

            // Check user data insert or update status
            if(!empty($userID)){
                $data['userData'] = $userData;
                $this->session->set_userdata('userData',$userData);
            } else {
               $data['userData'] = array();
            }

            // Get logout URL
            $data['logoutUrl'] = $this->facebook->logout_url();
        }else{
            $fbuser = '';

            // Get login URL
            $data['authUrl'] =  $this->facebook->login_url();
        }

        // Load login & profile view
        $this->load->view('user_authentication/index',$data);
    }

    public function logout() {
        // Remove local Facebook session
        $this->facebook->destroy_session();
        // Remove user data from session
        $this->session->unset_userdata('userData');
        // Redirect to login page
        redirect('/user_authentication');
    }
}
```

Below is my facebook file in config.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|  Facebook App details
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| To get an facebook app details you have to be a registered developer
| at http://developer.facebook.com and create an app for your project.
|
|  facebook_app_id               string   Your facebook app ID.
|  facebook_app_secret           string   Your facebook app secret.
|  facebook_login_type           string   Set login type. (web, js, canvas)
|  facebook_login_redirect_url   string   URL tor redirect back to after login. Do not include domain.
|  facebook_logout_redirect_url  string   URL tor redirect back to after login. Do not include domain.
|  facebook_permissions          array    The permissions you need.
|  facebook_graph_version        string   Set Facebook Graph version to be used. Eg v2.6
|  facebook_auth_on_load         boolean  Set to TRUE to have the library to check for valid access token on every page load.
*/

$config['facebook_app_id']              = '******';
$config['facebook_app_secret']          = '*****';
$config['facebook_login_type']          = 'web';
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'user_authentication';
$config['facebook_logout_redirect_url'] = 'user_authentication/logout';
$config['facebook_permissions']         = array('email');
$config['facebook_graph_version']       = 'v2.6';
$config['facebook_auth_on_load']        = TRUE;
```

My View file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login with Facebook in CodeIgniter by CodexWorld</title>
<style type="text/css">
h1{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#999999;
}
.wrapper{width:600px; margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;}
.welcome_txt{
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding: 10px;
    border: #D6D6D6 solid 1px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.fb_box{
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: #FFF0DD;
    padding: 10px;
    border: #F7CFCF solid 1px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.fb_box .image{ text-align:center;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(!empty($authUrl)) {

    echo '<a href="'.$authUrl.'"><img src="'.base_url().'assets/images/flogin.png" alt=""/></a>';
}else{
?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Facebook Profile Details </h1>
    <div class="welcome_txt">Welcome <b><?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?></b></div>
    <div class="fb_box">
        <p class="image"><img src="<?php echo $userData['picture_url']; ?>" alt="" width="300" height="220"/></p>
        <p><b>Facebook ID : </b><?php echo $userData['oauth_uid']; ?></p>
        <p><b>Name : </b><?php echo $userData['first_name'].' '.$userData['last_name']; ?></p>
        <p><b>Email : </b><?php echo $userData['email']; ?></p>
        <p><b>Gender : </b><?php echo $userData['gender']; ?></p>
        <p><b>Locale : </b><?php echo $userData['locale']; ?></p>
        <p><b>You are login with : </b>Facebook</p>
        <p><a href="<?php echo $userData['profile_url']; ?>" target="_blank">Click to Visit Facebook Page</a></p>
        <p><b>Logout from <a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Facebook</a></b></p>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever I press for facebook login it asks for permissions and throw me back at the same page with a code in link bar.
Before Login

```
http://localhost/bird_eye_api/user_authentication
```

After Login

```
http://localhost/bird_eye_api/user_authentication?code=AQBWssEFr4IVgC9gMBX3QUR_v7bSWU2F2Lj59-u89tRdSJTuinJNN3f9EC35F1yR8uWMeMq4JvQRlDk982sddLz5jJymqhh537WlyGYNv8mHnpIW3qhggSKwm3AEGiujf9jtD54FJGzM5OzAY-QF1GTnmHa3EiO_ZsF-iQKqlLYv3NfCd30U2004Dbw6OsYLFPLsuRFpgEkA3J2XTxPpWHPVhX2TDGEFU72qXqTcuaYWCrrOFvZBCbwVziXL9Run13W8ZBZ84rOjJKar-Pwh9v4pztJ0OG3SYLsK3OiTZoMGjQ8Gcb_dohJ0d5b5383lUdk&state=663d1106ff10826c01b08c4f1d1933d8#_=_
```

Any issues with Callback URL?

Comment: Have you try to add a callback url in your Facebook application settings?

Comment: No! I dnt cn u pls tell me how to?

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']
```

in your config.php to the url of page you want to return to.

For example:

```
$config['facebook_login_redirect_url']  = 'profile';
```

Don't forget to handle Facebook code on this page. It'll be like http://yoursite.com/bird_eye_api/profile?code=AABCCDDEEFF

Comment: I couldn't get the code! for handling these request, cn u provide me that>?